# Price configuration for child products

Tags: magento2, price-rules

I try to figure out how to setup price configuration on magento2. Having a base product which has a base price on 1 item I want to attach to this product multiple configurations for 50 item and 100 item  with different prices

```
Product_1 -1 item  --- 30 usd
  ---- Product_1_1 - 50 items - 56usd
  ---- Product_1_1 - 100 items - 86usd
```

all derived configurations should be visible in tab.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tier price feature to configure price with quantity in magento 2.0 for simple product and tier price available at product edit > advance setting > advance price tab.

Comment: thanks for feedback I configured the prices but do not show up in frontend

Comment: Please clear cache or if possible do indexing first.

Comment: I have been doing couple of times I think is related to the fact that I use a custom theme which inherits from blank

Comment: Ok If you have doubts in theme then change it as luma temporarily. Becoz I have check tier price from my setup it is working perfectly (with luma theme).

Comment: where should that show up I changed to lumen but still nothing

Comment: Its should show notification at product detail page at front-end.
i.e Buy 10 for $25.00 each and save 27%.